# Levene's test for ANCOVA in R shows no result

Tags: r

I want to conduct an ANCOVA with 3 covariates in R. Using the package "car", I want to conduct a Levene Test to check the assumption of Homogeneity of Variance.

```
library(car)
leveneTest(Daten$DependentVariable, 
    interaction(Daten$firstCovariate, Daten$secondCovariate, Daten$thirdCovariate, Daten$GroupingVariable), 
    center=median)
```

The result is the following, showing no significance value:

```
Levenes Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = mean)
    Df F value Pr(>F)
    group 133               
    0
```

My Covariates are all numeric. If I leave out `firstCovariate`, which is the age of the participants in days, it shows a result. Do you have any idea, what could be the problem with this covariate?

Comment: Can you provide some example data so that I can better understand your question?  You can use `dput(my_df)` as a quick way to do this or, if your data are large, do `dput(head(my_df))`.

Comment: I don't believe you need to have covariates in your test of homogeneity. It should just be `leveneTest(Daten$DV ~ Daten$IV, center = mean)`. This is because the Levene's test is only defined for one-way `ANOVAs`. Your covariates should only come into play during the `ANCOVA`.

Comment: You can also ask this question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) since this may be more of a statistics question, than a programming question.

Comment: Thank you @DanY and @Anonymouscoward! Unfortunately I can't provide data as it is from a research project. I asked the question an CrossValidated.